# Without using generics, is it possible in Typescript to have the type of a function output be used as the type of another function's input?

Tags: typescript

Normally using generics, one might declare a type with two functions where one function uses the output type of the other function as its input type like so

```
type ExampleType<T> = {
    function1: (param: number) => T;
    function2: (param: T) => number;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using generics?

I've tried to declare `ExampleType` like so

```
type ExampleType = {
    function1: (param: number) => any;
    function2: (param: ReturnType<ExampleType['function1']>) => number;
}
```

but the keyword `any` turns off all type checking such that

```
const example1: ExampleType = {
    function1: (param: number): string => {
        ...
    },
    function2: (param: number): number => {
        ...
    },
}
```

is allowed even though function1 returns values of type string, and function2 accepts values of type number.

Comment: Why no generics? What's the use case?  If someone asked you "without using this hammer in my hand, is it possible for me to drive a nail into a wall?", the answer "I guess you could try bashing it with a rock" is less responsible than "wait, what's wrong with using the hammer"?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without generics. I would suggest using something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrggHgwPigF4oBvAKCigDMBXAOwGNgBLAe3oEYAuKACjAIATsl71aSAEYQhASmKEMAbko0GzdvQBMvAcNFQM8ooXFSZKgL4ryjDgGdgapsSh58fYQHN7veMjRMbHdjQm97GzomPgoqKI0OHn5BESQxCWk5XkchFnovBTJVKiEIYFoheigAcgR7ABNqlSpLABpVeNYOHWT9JFl08yFC2KooUvLKqABqFORmqDbyS1kVIA). Does it work for you?